Splunk query to get uncommon result
I want a simple query which will return a uncommon values from. currently below query returns union of both expected and actual i.e. "Xray,Perform,Report,Hyper,Xray,Perform"
I want result like "Report,Hyper".
| makeresults 
| eval Expected = "Xray,Perform,Report,Hyper"
| makemv delim="," Expected
| eval Actual = "Xray,Perform"
| makemv delim="," Actual
| eval Combined = mvappend(Expected, Actual)
| makemv delim="," Combined
| stats count by Combined
| where count=1
| table Combined

I tried different options but didnt work

Try this query:
| makeresults 
| eval Expected = "Xray,Perform,Report,Hyper"
| makemv delim="," Expected
| eval Actual = "Xray,Perform"
| makemv delim="," Actual
| mvexpand Expected
| eval t1=mvfind(Actual,Expected)
| where isnull(t1)
| stats values(Expected) AS Results


Explanation:

Expanding Expected generates one row per expected result
mvfind() searches, for the index of Expected in Actual; returns null if missing
where filters for missings in Actual
stats aggregates into MV field

